# C system calls - Executing a process that closes its file?

Tags: c, exec, system-calls, file-descriptor

Basically, I came up with a weird thought experiment when doing some homework for a systems programming class. The behaviour I got back was a little surprising, I was wondering if someone could explain what's going on.

I have these two source files:

**prog.c:**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", close(3));

    return 0;
}
```

**shell.c:**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char **environ;

int main()
{
    char *args[] = {"prog", NULL};
    int fd = open("prog", O_RDONLY);

    fexecve(fd, args, environ);

    printf("-> %d\n", close(fd));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run `shell` it opens up `prog`, which gets the file descriptor 3. When I run `fexecve` it calls prog, which closes FD 3, prints the return value, and exits. Essentially, I'm executing a file [which does nothing but close itself!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3DBA.gif)

What I found odd is that when I do this, the second print statement (`shell.c:14`) is never reached because
control never returns to the shell program. `return 0;` in `prog` terminates the entire process. I investigated by stepping through with gdb:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40065e: file shell.c, line 9.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/kebertx/shell 

Breakpoint 1, main () at shell.c:9
9           char *args[] = {"prog", NULL};
(gdb) n
10          int fd = open("prog", O_RDONLY);
(gdb) 
12          fexecve(fd, args, environ);
(gdb) 
process 4256 is executing new program: /home/kebertx/prog

Breakpoint 1, main () at prog.c:6
6           printf("%d\n", close(3));
(gdb) 
0
8           return 0;
(gdb) 
9       }
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7a58800 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function __libc_start_main,
which has no line number information.
[Inferior 1 (process 4256) exited normally]
(gdb) quit
```

My intuition is failing me here. FD 3 is closed successfully, but that causes the program to get lost. Shouldn't `fexecve` be on the call stack? Why does the file of the subprocess need to be open in order for exec to find its way back home? What are the exec functions doing, and what are they not able to do when I break it like this?

I don't expect this to ever be something I need to know for practical applications, but I'm a curious. Any explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: `man fexecve: [...]A  successful  call to fexecve() never returns. `.

Comment: @EOF - that should be an answer, as it is *the* answer, and unless the question is changed, the end of the story.

Comment: ... Meaning the behaviour is the same if `prog` doesn't do anything at all. That's weird, I thought I read that man page more carefully than I did.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: You expect me to write a single-line answer to a two-page question? Tempting, but no.

Comment: @EOF - up to you or not.  Someone's going to write it and get credit for it (looks like someone already has).  Or not? what's with the deletion?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: And it's gone. Pity, I was going to upvote...

Comment: Stackoverflow politics are weird... Thank you for answering my question, @EOF !

Comment: @kebertx: You have the opportunity to answer your own question! If you make it a good, long, informative answer, it may be useful to others.